# Javascript does not execute when I add the IsBrowserInitializedChanged event

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

my javascript code is not running when I post the event:
IsBrowserInitializedChanged. However, if I remove the event, the code will work, but the error will occur later.

Code:

```
 chromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (chromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
                {
                    chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(codejavascript);
                }
            };
```

Comment: What is with  `+=` ?

Comment: I got this code from the internet because I had the error "IsBrowserInitializedChanged" but I am not able to execute my JavaScript code.
What I changed was just the javascript code for my

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript